# vb.net - Display docx & xlsx files in Webview2 control

Tags: vb.net, xlsx, docx, preview, webview2

I'm working on a project in .net that has a need for a document preview function.

I've implemented a Webview2 control and, as the majority of doucments that need to be viewed are pdf, this works a treat.

However, now and again some documents may be in either docx or xlsx format.
When I set webview2.Source = New Uri(PathtoFile) on these files, the webview2 control downloads the document to my downloads folder rather than rendering it.

I get that the files are not HTML, but then again neither are PDFs and they work out of the box.

Is there some mechanism I'm missing whereby I can have the Webview2 control display the file contents for docx and xlxs rather than download?

Comment: PDFs work because Microsoft has specifically built a PDF reader into Edge. There is no such reader built in for Office files. There are ActiveX controls for Office apps that could open documents in IE but I don't think that those are supported in Edge. If you can't open those documents in Edge then you can't open them in a `WebView2`. Maybe you could use a `WebBrowser` control for Office documents specifically, so the Office ActiveX controls will be supported. An alternative might be to use Office online, although I'm not confident that would support local files.

Comment: @jmcilhinney All correct except *If you can't open those documents in Edge then you can't open them in a WebView2*. Not necessarily. WebView2 uses the rendering engine, but other implementations may apply specifically to Edge (Chromium). You can see the difference also with a PDF: not the same thing. -- Next step is: [Microsoft Edge WebView2 and Microsoft 365 Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/webview2-install)

Comment: @Jimi, I haven't read that page in detail but, at a glance, it seems to be talking about WebView2 in Office rather than Office in WebView2. It says that Office 365 apps use a WebView2 control to display web content, not that a WebView2 can be used to display Office 365 documents. I understand that WebView2 is not Edge but it is basically a subset of Edge, like the AxWebBrowser control is a subset of IE, so, out of the box, it won't be able to do things that Edge can't. That said, there may well be factors that I'm not taking into account so I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sure, both use Chromium. But the implementation matters. Not everything is *surfaced*. The WebView2 Control has it's own implementation of the Chromium API (it's in a public repository), The Edge app has it's own. -- Yes, Office (365+) will of course use Chromium for integration: IE has already been dismissed and the old Edge is about to be. An *interpreter* (as Google's Document View) is required to present an Office document in a WebBrowers.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same problem ourselves. At the moment we are using a product called Aspose that will allow us to convert Word Documents to XPS, after which we can display the document in a Document Viewer.

While this works, and it works **well**, the main problem is that this relies on us downloading the document, then converting it and then loading the converted document into the Viewer. Which causes a certain perception of "sluggishness" due to all of that work, whereas images and PDFs, especially when hosted on the Web, can be hosted directly in the WebView2 and this then leaves the rest of our application nicely responsive to user interaction.

So in case anyone comes up with a better suggestion, I'm following this ...

The code using Aspose is pretty straightforward (example in Visual Basic .NET):

```
Dim oDoc As Aspose.Words.Document = Nothing
oDoc = New Aspose.Words.Document(sFile)
oDoc.Save(fileName:=sToFileName, saveFormat:=Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Xps)
```

(left out all error handling and so on in order to focus on the actual functionality. sToFileName just contains a filename along the lines of [somefolder][yourtargetfilename].xps ...)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may try to convert [DOCX to PDF](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/convert-a-document-to-pdf/#converting-doc-or-docx-to-pdf) directly via Aspose.Words and [XLSX to PDF](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/convert-excel-workbook-to-pdf/) via Aspose.Cells. Both these APIs support rendering to PDF or even image formats. Since your viewer supports to view PDF or images, so you may try this approach, it might work for your needs.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.